# Passing arrays and recursive functions error

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, recursion

I am trying to make a merge sort work, I have been trying to debug the problem on my own, but i can't see it. I could use some help.
As I said, I have a merge sort which gives me totally random numbers. I believe it's because of the array parameter that I try to transmit through 2 functions but I am not sure.

EDIT: So I found 2 errors

First i was not incrementing i while going through the array parts

```
while(lim1<=mid && lim2<=end)
{
    if(*(a+lim1)<=*(a+lim2))
    {
        *(aux+i)=*(a+lim1);
        lim1++;
    }
    else
    {
        *(aux+i)=*(a+lim2);
        lim2++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Second was that I was adding random values because aux array was bigger that it was supposed to (At first i thought it wouldn't matter)
changed by this:

```
int s=end-start;
int aux[s];/*So I wil only have 
             the required value 
             without any random values
            */
```

But I still get wrong values, no more randoms though, seems like it duplicates the values now. 
Edit2: Changed the names of my 2 functions.

Edit3: Spaced out the code

```
/*
Program description: Program that sorts an array using merge sort
Author: Andrei Negura
Date: 12/07/2017
Os: win 10
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define START 0
#define SIZE 10
void sort(int *, int, int);
void merge(int *, int, int, int);
void read(int *);
void display(int *);

int main()
{
   int array[ SIZE ];

    read( array );
    display( array );
    printf("\n");
    merge( array, START, SIZE-1);
    display( array );
    return 0;
}

void read(int *a)
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter %d elements\n", SIZE);
    for(i= START; i< SIZE; i++)
        scanf("%d", &*(a+i) );
}

void display(int *a)
{
    int i;
    printf("\nElements\n");
    for( i= START; i< SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d ", *(a+i) );

}
/*
  Function that divides the array into subarrays
  Divide and conquer method
  Recursive function
*/
void sort(int *a, int start, int end)
{
    int mid;
    if( start< end)
    {
        mid= ( start + end) / 2;
        merge( a, start, mid);
        merge( a, mid+1, end);
        sort( a, start, mid, end);
    }
}
/*
  Function that actually sorts the elements
  lim1 and lim2 will act as index values,
  that's why Idon't use the parameters
  The parameters will be my limits(until
  what point lim1 and lim2 go)
  Auxiliary Array to store the sorted array
*/
void merge(int *a, int start, int mid, int end)
{
    int s= end - start;
    int aux[s];//So I wil only have \
                the required value \
                without any random values

    int i=0;
    int lim1= start, lim2= mid+1;
    /*
    The I does not reset, If i reset i,
    I lose the count for the auxiliary array
    */
    /*
    Go through both parts of the array at once
    until one of them is finished
    */
    while(lim1 <= mid && lim2 <= end)
    {
        if( *( a + lim1 ) <= *( a + lim2 ) )
        {
            *( aux + i ) = *( a + lim1 );
            lim1++;
        }
        else
        {
            *( aux + i ) = *( a + lim2 );
            lim2++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    //Go through first part, if not finished already
    while( lim1 <= mid)
    {
        *( aux + i ) = *( a + lim1 );
        i++;
        lim1++;
    }
    //Go through second part, if not finished already
    while( lim2 <= end)
    {
        *( aux + i )= *( a + lim2);
        i++;
        lim2++;
    }

    //Rewrite the sorted array back into a
    for( i = START; i <= s; i++)
        *( a + i )= *( aux + i );
}
```

Comment: `&*(a+i)` - Are you trying to obfuscate your code? And I don't understand your recursion. Merge sort is working by first sorting two halves, an then merging them. But you have something totally different. `merge` should be linear. `sort` should be recursive and call `merge`..

Comment: Try to work with indices like aux[i]. Can you post a sample output!

Comment: Why do you print the output of a in sort before changing the content of a?

Comment: I switched the names by mistake, it should have been sort for the recursive function and merge for the other. As I said, I was trying to debug it, see where it goes wrong. I believe the mistake is in the way i try to transmit parameter a further into the sort and merge function, but I am not sure of that and if that is the problem i am not sure what to write instead. As for the &*(a+i), it's just another way of writing arrays using subscript notation, i was told it's faster in big programs.

Comment: Do you think this bit of code `if(*(a+lim1)<=*(a+lim2))` is readable?

Comment: Your code is gibberish. Throw it away and start again

Comment: Also I rarely see `<=` in C code when invoked in loops

Comment: Can I ask why it's gibberish?